# Apply client_max_body_size for a single URL only while using rewrites

Tags: nginx

This question is similar to [Apply client_max_body_size for a single URL only](https://serverfault.com/questions/772579/apply-client-max-body-size-for-a-single-url-only/772584) but different due to the rewrite.

I'd like to allow larger body size on endpoint `lg`, but not on the others. My existing configuration looks like this:

```
location /xyz/ {
  rewrite ^/xyz/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://{{proxy_host}}:{{proxy_port}}/;
}
```

I want to do something like the below, but keep either getting errors, or it simply doesn't work:

```
location /xyz/ {
  rewrite ^/xyz/(.*) /$1 break;
  ...
  location /xyz/lg {
    client_max_body_size 2m;
  }
}
```

I tried using regex for the nested url but only got:

`nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location,`

Comment: Please edit your question and show the actual `location` block contents. The  `...` is probably significant.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith done

Comment: Your post does not contain the configuration which resulted in the error message you posted. Please edit your post to show the actual configuration which resulted in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The `rewrite...break` is unnecessary, as `proxy_pass` with a trailing `/` performs the same task, so your original `location` block can be simplified to:

```
location /xyz/ {
    proxy_pass http://{{proxy_host}}:{{proxy_port}}/;
}
```

The `client_max_body_size` statement needs to be placed within a `location` block, and that block also needs a `proxy_pass` statement, as that directive is not inherited.

For example:

```
location /xyz/ {
    proxy_pass http://{{proxy_host}}:{{proxy_port}}/;
}
location /xyz/lg {
    client_max_body_size 2m;
    proxy_pass http://{{proxy_host}}:{{proxy_port}}/lg;
}
```

You can probably nest the `location` blocks, but there is no point as there is nothing to inherit.

Notice that the `lg` part of the URI is added to both the new `location` statement and the new `proxy_pass` statement.

The example will set the `client_max_body_size` for any URI that *begins with* `/xyz/lg`, e.g. `/xyz/lg`, `/xyz/lgfoo` and `/xyz/lg/bar`.